# Converting very big integer to bit vector fails

Tags: java, overflow, biginteger, bit

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Factorial {

    public static int[] bitVector(int n) {
        ArrayList<Integer> bitList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        BigInteger input = computeFactorial(n);
        System.out.println(input);
        BigInteger[] result = input.divideAndRemainder(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(2)));
        if (result[0].intValue()==0) {return new int[]{result[1].intValue()};}
        else {
            bitList.add(result[1].intValue());
        }
        while(result[0].intValue() != 0) {
            result = result[0].divideAndRemainder(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(2)));
            bitList.add(result[1].intValue());
        }
        int[] array = new int[bitList.size()];
        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
            array[i]=bitList.get(i).intValue();
        }
        return array;
    }

    public static BigInteger computeFactorial(int n) {
        if (n==0) {
            return new BigInteger(String.valueOf(1));
        } else {
            return new BigInteger(String.valueOf(n)).multiply(computeFactorial(n-1));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] bitVector = bitVector(35);
        for (int bit: bitVector)
        System.out.print(bit+" ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The code above works fine when the input to `bitVector` is no bigger than `35`. However, when I pass `36` as a parameter to `bitVector`, all but one bit are gone in the output.

I have potentially ruled out the following causes:

1. It may have nothing to do with the BigInteger type since it was designed to never overflow.
2. It may not be related to memory usage of the program, which uses only `380M` at runtime.
3. I print out the value of `computeFactorial(36)`, which looks good.

What on earth is going on there?

Comment: `BigInteger.testBit` and also `BigInteger.valueOf` might be of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you are trying to do is

```
public static String factorialAsBinary(int n) {
    BigInteger bi = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (; n > 1; n--)
        bi = bi.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(n));
    return bi.toString(2);
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    String fact36 = factorialAsBinary(36);
    for (char ch : fact36.toCharArray())
        System.out.print(ch + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

which prints

1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

> What on earth is going on there?

Your code is much more complicated than it needs to be which also makes it easier to make mistakes and harder to understand.

Answer (score 1):

`result[0].intValue()` is wrong:

intValue():

*Converts this BigInteger to an int. This conversion is analogous to a narrowing primitive conversion from long to int as defined in the Java Language Specification: if this BigInteger is too big to fit in an int, only the low-order 32 bits are returned. Note that this conversion can lose information about the overall magnitude of the BigInteger value as well as return a result with the opposite sign.*

in your case it returns the lowest 32 bits which are zero therefore you return 0 after first devision

Comment: Thank you very much for making it clear for me. Very helpful!